# kdb+: function with two arguments from columns

Tags: kdb

I have a function that does something with a date and a function that takes two arguments to perform a calculation. For now let's assume that they look as follows:

```
d:{[x] :x.hh}
f:{[x;y] :x+y}
```

Now I want to use function `f` in a query as follows:

```
select f each (columnOne,d[columnTwo]) from myTable
```

Hence, I first want to convert one column to the corresponding numbers using function `d`. Then, using both `columnOne` and the output of `d[columnTwo]`, I want to calculate the outcome of `f`.

Clearly, the approach above does not work, as it fails with a `'rank` error.

I've also tried `select f ./: (columnOne,'d[columnTwo]) from myTable`, which also doesn't work.

How do I do this? Note that I need to input `columnOne` and `columnTwo` into `f` such that the corresponding rows still match. E.g. input row 1 of `columnOne` and row 1 of `columnTwo` simultaneously into `f`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I've also tried `select f ./: (columnOne,'d[columnTwo]) from myTable`, which also doesn't work.

You're very close with that code. The issue is the `d` function, in particular the `x.hh` within function `d` - the `.hh` notation doesn't work in this context, and you will need to do `` `hh$x `` instead, so `d` becomes:

```
d:{[x] :`hh$x}
```

So making only this change to the above code, we get:

```
q)d:{[x] :`hh$x}
q)f:{[x;y] :x+y}
q)myTable:([] columnOne:10?5; columnTwo:10?.z.t);
q)update res:f ./: (columnOne,'d[columnTwo]) from myTable
    columnOne columnTwo    res
    --------------------------
    1         21:10:45.900 22
    0         20:23:25.800 20
    2         19:03:52.074 21
    4         00:29:38.945 4
    1         04:30:47.898 5
    2         04:07:38.923 6
    0         06:22:45.093 6
    1         19:06:46.591 20
    1         10:07:47.382 11
    2         00:45:40.134 2
```

(I've changed `select` to `update` so you can see other columns in result table)

Other syntax to achieve the same:

```
q)update res:f'[columnOne;d columnTwo] from myTable
    columnOne columnTwo    res
    --------------------------
    1         21:10:45.900 22
    0         20:23:25.800 20
    2         19:03:52.074 21
    4         00:29:38.945 4
    1         04:30:47.898 5
    2         04:07:38.923 6
    0         06:22:45.093 6
    1         19:06:46.591 20
    1         10:07:47.382 11
    2         00:45:40.134 2
```

Only other note worthy point - in the above example, function `d` is vectorised (works with vector arg), if this wasn't the case, you'd need to change `d[columnTwo]` to `d each columnTwo` (or `d'[columnTwo]`)

This would then result in one of the following queries:

```
select res:f'[columnOne;d'[columnTwo]] from myTable
select res:f ./: (columnOne,'d each columnTwo) from myTable
select res:f ./: (columnOne,'d'[columnTwo]) from myTable
```

Comment: I will try this out. Actually my real `d` function does something else. I just made it `.hh` for this question. But this seems very helpful. Thank you!

Comment: Now that I think of it, both my `f` and `d` functions are probably *not* vector based. Hence both need some sort of `each` as input. How would the syntax work then? Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Never mind, I found the syntax myself (I've updated your answer with some example queries). It was the same as you proposed. Thanks again :)